# Can't copy and paste into Outlook 2003 from any other aplication

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, copy-paste

I am having an issue with Outlook 2003 where I cannot copy and paste anything from any other application into an email that I'm working on. I have tried copying from Excel, Word, Notepad and from a web browser.

I can confirm that I can copy and paste parts from the same email. Has anyone come across this issue before and/or know of a solution?

Comment: Did you manage to fix your issue since October 09?

Answer (score 1):

If outlook is running as remoteapp it might have clipboard redirection disabled.

Answer (score 0):

When that happens to me I end up copying the entire email and restarting Outlook. You might also want to try copying the entire email (body) and then closing the message. Open a new message and paste what you had into it.

Other things to try:

Try pasting as unformatted text and see if that works. (Edit -> Paste Special -> Unformatted)

Try disabling all of your add-ons.

Detect and Repair your Outlook installation.