# Outlook 365 - Cannot paste into an email I am editing

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, copy-paste, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have recently upgraded from Office 2010 to Office 365.
Now while editing emails I cannot paste any contents (text or images), regardless of the format (HTML/Text/RTF). I cannot selecct and drag within the email either.

I can copy from my email and paste elsewhere.

I found no info on this, other than (which did not help):

[Can't copy and paste into Outlook 2003 from any other aplication](https://superuser.com/questions/52522/cant-copy-and-paste-into-outlook-2003-from-any-other-aplication)

[Outlook 2007 cannot copy paste (workaround/solution here)](https://superuser.com/questions/811892/outlook-2007-cannot-copy-paste-workaround-solution-here)

Answer (score 0):

It Works now. Ido not know what was the change that helped. It may be one of these:

1. I followed [this](https://superuser.com/a/811893/245595), which did not help at that point. Then I undid those changes (which did not help either).
2. I reset the PC for some automatic Win 7 updates to complete installation.

Now pasting works ok. So I wouldn't know if (e.g.) the combination of step 1 above and exiting/restarting Outlook would have sufficed.
There is no way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't paste into my msn.com email compositions! Then I tried to paste into my GMX.com email, again, No Go. But the GMX mail provided a pop-up with an explanation of a browser problem causing this.
The pop-up also presented a work-around: Ctrl+V will paste into the email!
Good Luck!